# Python recreate instance inside class inheritance-safe

Tags: python, python-3.x, class, oop

I have no idea how to phrase this issue. I've created a Minimal Working Example below:

```
import math


class MyClass:
    def __init__(one, two):
        self.one = one
        self.two = two

    def to_logarithm():
        return MyClass(self.one, math.log(self.two))


class MyChildClass(MyClass):

    def __init__(one, two):
        super().__init__(one, two)
```

In the example above I have a parent class called `MyClass` which has a method called `to_logarithm`. This method just re-creates the instance of the class, but with the log of the parameter `two`.

Then, I have a child class that inherits from `MyClass`, so it also inherits the method `to_logarithm`. However, if I run the method, I will ofcourse get a `MyClass` instance. What I want to do, is that each child (that will have different behaviors) will basically create an instance as itself, just with log value. That is, I would like that if I call `MyChildClass.to_logarithm()` I will basically get `MyChildClass(self.one, math.log(self.two))` without having to overwrite the method and hard-code it. Is there a way?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use `self.__class__`. It'll be the class object of the current instance.

Your original code is also missing some `self`s.

```
import math

class MyClass:
    def __init__(self, one, two):
        self.one = one
        self.two = two

    def to_logarithm(self):
        return self.__class__(self.one, math.log(self.two))


class MyChildClass(MyClass):
    pass


print(MyClass(1, 5).to_logarithm())
print(MyChildClass(1, 5).to_logarithm())
```

prints out

```
<__main__.MyClass object at 0x10b7c15c0>
<__main__.MyChildClass object at 0x10b7b8550>
```